# Using TreeView to display data from wcf connection

Tags: wcf-data-services

i have a WCF that connect with the database and it retrieve data from the NOrthWind database using Employee table, i want this intormation to be displayed in the windows form using treeview control. The information in the Northwind database in the Employee table need to be displayed in a treeview control.

Answer (score 0):

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        EmpTree.Employee display = new EmpTree.Employee();

        TreeNode head = new TreeNode();

        TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        head = new TreeNode("Employee Details");

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(head);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent);

        Fillchild(tnParent);

    }

    //=========================================Fill Child With Data========================================
    public void Fillchild(TreeNode parent)
    {

        EmpTree.Service1Client myDisplay = new EmpTree.Service1Client();

        foreach (var employee in myDisplay.getEmployees())
        {
             TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
             child.Nodes.Add("Employee ID" + " " + employee.Employee_ID.ToString());
             child.Nodes.Add("Employee First Name" + " " + employee.FirstName);
             child.Nodes.Add("Employee Last Name:" + " " + employee.LastName);
             child.Nodes.Add("Employee Title:" + " " + employee.Title);
             child.Nodes.Add("birth Date:" + " " + employee.BirthDate.ToLongDateString());
             child.Nodes.Add("Home Phone No:" + " " + employee.HomePhone);
             child.Nodes.Add("Report To:" + " " + employee.ReportsTo.ToString());
             parent.Nodes.Add(child);
        } 
    }
```